# How do you call fat arrow function stored in string without using eval?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

How do you call fat arrow function like below (stored in string) without using eval?

```
"g => { alert(g); }"
```

With using eval, the below code is working fine, but I want to avoid using eval.

```
eval("g => { alert(g); }")('hello')
```

I hope I could do something like below using "new Function", but I have no luck so far.

```
new Function("g => { alert(g); }")('hello')
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Any method which parses a string containing JavaScript is effectively going to run `eval()` on it.

Comment: Write your own js engine. Or take one of those out there.

Comment: Basically, there's javascript (fat arrow function) code like above stored in the database. And I want to invoke such function in string without using eval when the page loads. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Then for your use case, I'd just bite the bullet and use `eval()`. Though I'd definitely try to refactor the application to not store JavaScript in the database; [separation of data and code is important](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/229479/how-did-separation-of-code-and-data-become-a-practice).

Comment: Hi @user9494009, were the answers here helpful? If so, consider [marking the best one as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

> The Function constructor creates a new Function object. Calling the constructor directly can create functions dynamically, but suffers from security and performance issues similar to **eval**.

that said, you can easyly parse your string to use function constructor, for example:

```js
const str = [g,body] =  "g => { console.log(g); }".split(" => ");

var myFunc = new Function(g, body);
myFunc("hello");


const str2 = [args,body] = "(h,i) => {console.log(h,i);}".split(" => ");
const [h,i] = args.replace(/\(|\)/g,"").split(",");
var myFunc2 = new Function(h,i, body);
myFunc2("hello","buddy");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Anything you do, including your own JS interpreter, is going to be a functional equivalent to `eval`.** Calling `eval()` function is not a security gap by itself. Executing unsanitized code is what is a security issue, and that's the thing you are trying to do here. **Using `eval` or *any equivalent* creates an XSS vulnerability.**

If you use real interpreter written in JS, you may be able to sandbox the code and mitigate the risk, but it's still a grey area.

OTOH, if you have valid reasons to consider the code in question to be sanitized, there's no good reason to not use `eval`.

Be aware that you can't reliably sanitize JS code. [Anything can be done with very little JS syntax available](http://www.jsfuck.com/), so **either the code is from a trusted source or it should never be run**.

All that said, perhaps the simplest way to get your function compiled with `new Function` is

```
(new Function('return ('+code+')'))()
```

This is almost exact equivalent to calling `eval(code)`, just without any access to the local namespace. Using `eval()` directly should be slightly faster (omits creating unnecessary function object).

Comment: @JackGiffin, nope, you are wrong. If used to be a direct equivalent of `eval()`, just as in the code I proposed above (i.e. create a function, call it, throw is away), `Function()` is slower than `eval()`. It is also not necessarily faster to call `Function('a', 'b', functionBody)(a, b)` than to call `eval('(a, b) => '+expression)(a, b)`. At least, the difference not reliable (and not significant anyway). [See a simple benchmark](https://jsfiddle.net/0wxfedjj/1/). Increase the repetitions number to get reliable results. Also, performance varies quite wildly depending on the browser.

Comment: @JackGiffin I saw your edit attempt. Please refrain from claiming that `eval` is slower, at least until you show a reliable benchmark showing that. All the evidence I have, prove that this claim is false. Common sense dictates it as well.

Answer (score 0):

in theory, this works. Still seems like a bad idea.

```
var fatso = "g => { alert(g); }";
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.innerText = "function callMe(f) { var a = " + fatso + "; a(f) }"
document.head.appendChild(s);
callMe("hello");
```

Comment: What if you want to evaluate millions of these? Then you would need millions of DOM nodes. Not a very practical idea.

Comment: @JackGiffin it's clearly not a practical idea. That's why in the first line of my post I stated "seems like a bad idea"